# nvcc fatal : Failed to detect host compiler properties

Tags: nvcc

I'm using nvcc in a very standard way:

```
nvcc -ccbin g++ mycode.cu
```

And it's suddenly stopped working, giving the error:

> nvcc fatal : Failed to detect host compiler properties

Why might this be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the issue was caused by the root partition running out of memory, as verified by `df -h`:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p2      24G   23G     0 100% /
```

As a quick way to get memory back, I ran:

```
sudo apt clean
```

Which recovered 2.4GB.

After this, `nvcc` again works without problems.